# Start process and terminate at later stage

Tags: linux, ipc, rpc

In am writing an SDK in Go that integrators will communicate with via a local socket connection.

From the integrating application I need a way to start the SDK as a process but more importantly, I need to be able to cancel that process when the main application is closing too.

This question is language agnostic (I think) as I think the challenge is linux related. i.e. How to start a program and cancel it at a later stage.

Some possible approaches:

- I am thinking that it's a case of starting the program via exec, getting it's PID or some ID then using that to kill later. Sudo may be required to do this, which is not ideal. Also, not good practice as you will be effectively force closing the SDK, offering no time for cleanup.
- Start the program via any means. Once ready to close, just send a "shutdown" command via the SDK API which will allow the SDK to cleanup, manage state then exit the application.

What is best practice for this please?

Comment: 1) why would you use `sudo` to terminate a process that you created? It should have the same privileges of the calling program. 2) Any reason why you excluded `signals` a priori?

Comment: 1) I wasn't sure if you required sudo to kill a process in general. 2) I'm not aware of signals.. please elaborate..

Comment: 1) as far as I know, no 2) Given a signal, you can setup a signal handler for it, that is a function that is triggered whenever the signal is asynchronously delivered to the process through an interrupt. So you can send a specific signal to your application, and define a signal handler that graciously terminates it by properly deallocating its resources. The specifics might depend on the technology you're using (processes, posix threads, etc.). You can find more about it here -> http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using Linux or similar Unix:

You are on the right track.  You won't need sudo.  The comments thus far are pointing in the right direction, but not spelling out the details.

See section 2 of the manual pages (`man 2 ...`) for details on the functions mentioned here.  They are documented for calling from C.  I don't have experience with Go to help determine how to use them there.

The integrator application will be called the "parent" process.  The SDK-as-a-process will be called the "child" process.  A process creates a child and becomes its parent by calling fork().  The new process is a duplicate of the parent, running the same code, and having for the most part all the same state (data in memory).  But fork() returns different values to parent and child, so each can determine its role in the relationship.  This includes informing the parent of the process identifier (pid) of the child.  Hang on to this value.  Then, the child uses exec() to execute a different program within the existing process, i.e. your SDK binary.  An alternative to fork-then-exec is posix_spawn(), which has rather involved parameters (but gives greater control if you need it).

Designing the child to shutdown in response to a signal, rather than a command through the API, will allow processes other than the parent to initiate clean shutdown in standard fashion.  For example, this might be useful for the administrator or user; it enables sending the shutdown signal from the shell command-line or script.

The child installs a signal handler function, that will be called when the child process receives a signal, by calling signal() (or the more complex sigaction() recommended for its portability).  There are different signals that can be sent/received, identified by different integer values (and also given names like SIGTERM).  You indicate which you're interested in receiving when calling signal().  When your signal handler function is invoked, you've received the signal, and can initiate clean shutdown.

When the parent wants the child to shut down cleanly, the parent sends a signal to the child using the unfortunately named kill().  Unfortunately named because signals can be used for other purposes.  Anyway, you pass to kill() the pid (returned by fork()) and the specific signal (e.g. SIGTERM) you want to send.

The parent can also determine when the child has completely shut down by calling waitpid(), again passing the pid returned by fork(); or alternately by registering to receive signal SIGCHLD.  Register to receive SIGCHLD *before* fork()/exec() or you might miss the signal.

Actually, it's important that you do call waitpid(), optionally after receiving SIGCHLD, in order to deallocate a resource holding the child process's exit status, so the OS can cleanup that last remnant of the process.  Failing to do so keeps the child as a "zombie" process, unable to be fully reclaimed.  Too many zombies and the OS will be unable to launch new processes.

If a process refuses to shut down cleanly or as quickly as you require, you may force it to quit (without executing its cleanup code) by sending the signal SIGKILL.

There are variants of exec(), waitpid() and posix_spawn(), with different names and behaviors, mentioned in their man pages.